# Showing data in a view blade from value join Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have multiple join table, and i want to binding in view blade use alias in select, his is my controller to join and select column:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $transaksi = Transaksi::find($id);
    $detail_transaksi = DetailTransaksi::whereIn('transaksi_id',$transaksi)
    ->join('transaksi', 'detail_transaksi.transaksi_id', 'transaksi.id')
    ->join('paket', 'detail_transaksi.paket_id', 'paket.id')
    ->join('kendaraan', 'detail_transaksi.kendaraan_id', 'kendaraan.id')
    ->join('pelanggan', 'transaksi.pelanggan_id', 'pelanggan.id')
    ->leftJoin('pencuci as p1', 'transaksi.pencuci_id', 'p1.id')
    ->leftJoin('pencuci as p2', 'transaksi.pencuci2_id', 'p2.id')
    ->select('detail_transaksi.transaksi_id as id',
    'transaksi.tanggal_transaksi as tanggal_transaksi',
    'pelanggan.name as nama_pelanggan',
    'p1.name as nama_pencuci1')
    ->get();
    return view('invoice',['detail_transaksi'=>$detail_transaksi]);
}
```

and In a view i use the join result as follows :

```
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->id}}</strong>
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->nama_pelanggan}}</strong>
```

but i get eror like this:

[image]

Thankyou for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `get()`, this method will be return a `Illuminate\Database\Collection`. You can call `Collection::first()` to get first element of collection:

```
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->first()->id}}</strong>
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->first()->nama_pelanggan}}</strong>
```

Or, use `first()` to replace `get()` on query eloquent:

```php
$detail_transaksi = DetailTransaksi::whereIn('transaksi_id',$transaksi)
    ->join('transaksi', 'detail_transaksi.transaksi_id', 'transaksi.id')
    ->join('paket', 'detail_transaksi.paket_id', 'paket.id')
    ->join('kendaraan', 'detail_transaksi.kendaraan_id', 'kendaraan.id')
    ->join('pelanggan', 'transaksi.pelanggan_id', 'pelanggan.id')
    ->leftJoin('pencuci as p1', 'transaksi.pencuci_id', 'p1.id')
    ->leftJoin('pencuci as p2', 'transaksi.pencuci2_id', 'p2.id')
    ->select(
        'detail_transaksi.transaksi_id as id',
        'transaksi.tanggal_transaksi as tanggal_transaksi',
        'pelanggan.name as nama_pelanggan',
        'p1.name as nama_pencuci1'
    )
    ->first(); // Replace here
```

Eloquent will return first match row, and class is your model `DetailTransaksi`:

```
var_dump( class_basename($detail_transaksi) );

// string(15) DetailTransaksi
```

No need to change the view, it should work fine.

```
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->id}}</strong>
<strong>{{$detail_transaksi->nama_pelanggan}}</strong>
```

---

Reference:

- [Eloquent: Getting Started > Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#collections)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started > Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)
- [Eloquent: Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $detail_transaksi = DetailTransaksi::whereIn('transaksi_id',$transaksi)

    ....

    ->first();
```